# How to immediately lock out a user using Claims Based Authorization in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

**Background**:

I'm an administrator for a site which uses AspNet Identity and MVC 5.

A user's request to view/edit etc. information on the site is judged on the basis of his or her claims

These claims are issued when the users log in and are stored on their machines in a cookie

When they log in, they also get an authentication cookie which has a lifetime of two weeks

**Scenario**:

I want to deny a rogue user access to areas of my site that he previously had access to.

**Question**:

Given that the rogue user logged in two minutes before I wiped his claims from the database, do I have to wait up to two weeks before he is forced to log in again and his claims cookie is refreshed?

If this is the case, what do i need to change to ensure that I can immediately lock out rogue users?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SignOutFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //...   if (cachedListOfBannedUsers.Contains(...))
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();

        //...
    }
}
```